# Enable webcam in docker application and access thru AWS ECS

Tags: python, docker, opencv, amazon-ec2, webcam

our requirement is , using docker we need to detect webcam from internet (amazon EC2)

using cv2 we are trying to detect the webcam from internet by leveraging on AWS ECS.

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

we are not getting any error but no webcam is detected when we run it from AWS EC2.

using the below command i executed the docker. still it is not working

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --privileged -v /dev/video0:/dev/video0
dockimage
```

FYI:
    We have created docker images in ubuntu VM 16.04

Thanks
Avi

Comment: Does it work without docker? Is your container dying?

Comment: Without docker it is working perfectly. The container is not dying.

Comment: AWS doesn't have webcams, so I don't understand how you are mounting  /dev/video0

Comment: I think web drivers r not installed. my ubuntu kernel version: 4.4.0-83 . how to install webcam drivers ?

Comment: Drivers for what? Again, AWS doesn't have webcams plugged into their servers, as far as I know.